# Some of text are not converting to installed arabic language pack, how to change them?

Tags: magento

I have installed an arabic language pack for a magento 1.9 project but some text is not getting changed to arabic language. How to change them?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps:

1. Go to your backend: Admin > System > Configuration > Developer
2. Select Arabic store view scope on the top left
3. Set Translate Inline > Enabled for Frontend to Yes
4. Now you are able to translate text on the store view frontend

Answer (score 1):

The language pack has some CSV in app/locale folder, open the CSV files and put your text with the appropriate targeted language in CSV manner.

If you describe where is the text, it may help me to describe in more details